# Assembly code returning sum of values in an array

Tags: c, assembly, arm, armv7

I have been provided the c code that the assembly code pulls from, but I thought I had the correct assembly code however I am unable to get the correct output.
Assembly:

```
.global countMatches

.text

countMatches:
   MOV R2, R0
   MOV R0, #0
countMatches_loop:
   LDR R3, [R2], #4
   CMP R3, #0
   ADDMI R0, R0, #1
   SUBS R1, R1, #1
   BNE countMatches_loop
     BX LR
```

The C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

extern uint32_t countMatches(char str[], char toMatch);

#define COUNT 5

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrss";
    printf("Question 8, countMatches: Correct Answer = 2\n");
    printf("Question 8, countMatches: Student Answer = %u\n\n", countMatches(str, 'g'));

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My current output:

Question 8, countMatches: Correct Answer = 2

Question 8, countMatches: Student Answer = 26

Comment: It looks like you're supposed to be counting matching bytes, but you're loading and comparing 32-bit integers.  Also, why are you comparing against 0, instead of the character you were passed?

Comment: You seem to be using the second argument as a count of characters to be compared, but it's actually the character `toMatch`.  You need to look for a null byte to see when to end the loop.

Comment: It might be a good start to write the desired function in C first and get it working.  It's not clear if your difficulties are from misunderstanding the assembly instructions, or the overall algorithm.  As far as the asm though, are you familiar with the difference between `LDR` and `LDRB`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my best guess at what your function would look like in C:

```
uint32_t countMatches(char str[], char toMatch) {
    uint32_t r = 0;
    while (*str) {
        char c = *str++;
        if (c == toMatch) {
            r++;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

And here's my version in ARM assembly language:

```
.global countMatches
.text
countMatches:
  mov     r3, #0
  b       load
loop:
  cmp     r2, r1
  addeq   r3, r3, #1
load:
  ldrb    r2, [r0], #1
  cmp     r2, #0
  bne     loop
  mov     r0, r3
  bx      lr
```